# Canvas adds lines without drawing it

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas

I'm currently trying out WPF for the first time, because I have used WinForms before. I started with a little practice and wanted to create a program which draws a line to wherever you click on a canvas. I programatically added the line to the canvas, but it seems that it doesn't draw it. The lines become children of the canvas though.

**C# Code**

```
private ArrayList arl = new ArrayList();

    private void Canvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        drawArea.Children.Clear();

        arl.Add(Mouse.GetPosition(drawArea));
        Point[] points = new Point[arl.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < arl.Count; i++)
            points[i] = (Point)arl[i];

        Line[] lines = new Line[points.Length - 1];

        if(lines.Count() > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
            {
                lines[i] = new Line();
                lines[i].Stroke = SystemColors.WindowFrameBrush;

                lines[i].X1 = points[i + 1].X;
                lines[i].X2 = points[i].X;
                lines[i].Y1 = points[i + 1].Y;
                lines[i].Y2 = points[i].Y;
            }

            foreach (var item in lines)
                drawArea.Children.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="WPFttest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFttest"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="362" Width="525" MouseDown="Window_MouseDown" BorderBrush="Red" ResizeMode="NoResize" KeyDown="Window_KeyDown" WindowStyle="None">
<Grid x:Name="mainGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="362" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="525" OpacityMask="#00000000">
    <Canvas x:Name="drawArea" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="312" Margin="0,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="525" Background="White" MouseDown="Canvas_MouseDown">
    </Canvas>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="525" MouseDown="Grid_MouseDown_1" OpacityMask="#00000000" Background="#00000000"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: How thick is your line?

Comment: @BugFinder Default StrokeThickness is 1.

Comment: Remove the OpacityMask nonsense. At least from the top level Grid. Before using those things, read documentation (or a WPF book). In case you want to set the overall opacity of a UI element, set its Opacity property.